# Printing Barcodes on RuggedJet printer

Tags: printing, windows-mobile, barcode

I need to print a barcode on a Brother RuggedJet printer from a Window Mobile device. The SDK provided by brother does not have a method to do this.

However most printers have a native mode that you can put them into and then send escape sequences to do things like print barcodes. I've done this with other printers.

Does anyone know the native printer language for the Brother RuggedJet? And if so what are the escape code to print Code 123 barcodes.

Answer (score 0):

You should contact Brother's Customer Support to see if they can get you in touch with some department that deals with the SDK or Technical Documents for their products.

I use Code 128 for our Barcodes, and to get them to print out, I use the OnPaint event to write using e.Graphics. I could post some of that code here, if you can use Code 128, but most of it I found from someone else, and I honestly never took the time to understand what it is doing.

Comment: I don't want to create an image of a barcode and send it to the printer. I'd rather find the native commands that the printer needs to print a barcode in the desired symbology.

Comment: That's what a Printer Driver is for. :)

Comment: Show me the "printer driver" for windows mobile and I'll gladly use it. :)

Comment: Oh, I see what you are doing. We keep a PC plugged into our label printer with the Windows Printer Driver. Our mobile devices simply send a command over TCP/IP to that PC's IP Address, and the application on the PC prints the barcode. It is much simpler than what you are trying to do.